# How can I redirect to login page on 401 response in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0, interceptor

I'm working on a Angular 5 application using OAuth2 implicit flow.

I have services that perform HTTP calls, following one example of my services:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  public getAll(): Observable<Persona[]> {
    return this.http.get<Persona[]>("http://mywebservice/persone");
  }
}
```

I'm using interceptors for authorization and add custom attributes. Following my auth interceptor:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {

  }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem("access_token");
    if(accessToken)
    {
        request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
        });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

And following how I consume my services:

```
public myMethod() {
    this.myService.getAll().subscribe(
        result => {
            console.log(result);
        }, error => {
            // I don't want add redirection there...
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Now my need is that when any HTTP call receive 401 result, the application redirects the user to login page.

How can I obtain this result without code duplication?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Why not write another interceptor to do that?

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#handleerror

Comment: I suggest having a look at this example: https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app  . You should use a combination of route guards, route resolvers and http interceptors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can I access to response object with an interceptor? thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I resolved my problem changing my interceptor like following:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {

  }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem("access_token");
    if(accessToken)
    {
        request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
        });
    }

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I found the solution there: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: This is nice solution for handling the 401 error. But what about the catch block written in httprequest ? how to avoid it ?

Comment: Where did you get a router instance?

Comment: From where is this 'this.router" coming sir?

Comment: Not working in Angular 13. do method not supported

Answer (score 25):

Only to support new readers, notice that in angular 7 you should use pipe() instead of do() or catch():

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
    if (err.status === 401) {
        MyComponent.logout();
    }
    const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
        return throwError(error);
}));
```

Comment: as long as you use rxjs , then you are using the Angular way of solving issues . Thanks for the ideal solution 

Answer (score 5):

Here is for Angular 11

```
import {
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";
import HttpStatusCode from "src/app/models/enums/HttpStatusCode";
import { AuthenticationService } from "./authentication.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        return event;
      }),
      catchError(
        (
          httpErrorResponse: HttpErrorResponse,
          _: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
        ) => {
          if (httpErrorResponse.status === HttpStatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED) {
            this.authenticationService.redirectToLogin();
          }
          return throwError(httpErrorResponse);
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The following method declared in AuthenticationService

```
public redirectToLogin(path: string, queryParams: any) {
    this.router.navigate([path], {
        queryParams,
        queryParamsHandling: "merge",
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach the error handling to the common request handler:

```
return next.handle(request).catch(err => {
    if (err.status === 401) {
         // Redirect here
    }
}
```

You can import the router directly in the interceptor, but the proper way to do it is to create an authentication service or similar that imports the router and call it to do the redirection

Comment: Hi Siro, thanks but adding catch statement I obtain a generic runtime exception next.handle(...).catch is not a function.

Comment: HttpHandler returns an observable: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHandler
Maybe you have missed to import some rxjs capabilities, try adding this:
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
(The import may vary depending on the rxjs version you're using)